# How to set which archiver is used when executing `Extract here` menu command in file manager?

Tags: filemanager, archive, thunar, pcmanfm

I can see that I can change the default archiver etc but I do not think that this changes also the program that handles archives when using `Extract here` in right-click menu. Sometimes this command does not work and I have to open it in a program and then extract.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First go to an archive file then **right click** --> **properties** then from **open with tab** you can choose the **default application** to run as shown in the screen-shot :

[image]

Once you choose a default application it will be used every time you open a file of that type. 'extract here` will use the default application. That's for sure.

Comment: I know how to do that of course but was not convinced that this changes the default application that is used with `Extract here`. It seems that this last command is not working for some reason no matter the default application set. Maybe I should edit the question so as to emphasize that it is not about how to set the default archiver in general but about how to relate that to the `Extract here` command that it's not working here.

Comment: Once you choose a defualt application all other stuffs to do with a file is done by this application so 'extract here` will just use the default application. That's sure

Comment: thnx for stating that clearly